# Geolocation Based HTML (People outside the U.S. visiting my website, see different html code)

Tags: javascript, html, css, geolocation

I want people living outside the United States to know, when they visit my website http://www.kikbo.com, that we ship internationally. I want this fact to be displayed prominently, but I see no reason to distract people living in the United States with this, to them, useless detail.

Just to give you a general sense of what I'm going for:

```
if geolocation != US:
      html_code = "<p> free shipping!</p>"
else:
      html_code = "<p> we ship international!</p>"
```

How can I display different HTML based on the geolocation of the browser of the visitor?

(I know HTML, CSS, Javascript, and Python, and I'd prefer not to do any server-side scripting.)

Comment: I think the people living in the United States should also know that you ship international.

Comment: Okay, yeah I agree, but they don't need that to be displayed prominently.

The plan is to have the U.S. people get the "Free Shipping" and the non-U.S. people get the "Reasonable Int'l Shipping" force-fed to them in a very noticeable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use a GeoIP service such as http://www.maxmind.com/ or http://www.hostip.info/.

Then  use something like PHP to parse the country code and display the content you want.

Answer (score 0):

check out http://www.maxmind.com/app/javascript_city.  it brings back some functions for you to call using javascript, so its painless to do only in the front end without adding any backend code.